# How do I import a file only when it is modified?

Tags: dynamic, date-and-time, files-and-directories

I am trying to create a `Dynamic` code that will `Import` the contents of file only if it has been modified. I tried the following code:

```
DynamicModule[{
    fileDate=FileDate[file,"Modification"]
},
    fileContents=Import[file];"-- Last Updated: "<>DateString[]<> " --",
    TrackedSymbols:>{fileDate}
]
```

Needless to say, the file is big and takes a lot of time to import thus it should be dynamically checked whether it has been updated and if it has then the newest version of the file is imported right away.

Answer (score 2):

The following checks the file last modification date every 10 seconds. If it is different from the current file date, the file is imported and a message is printed. `TaskRemove[obj]` will remove the task.

```
fileDate = FileDate[file];
fileContents = Import[file];
obj = SessionSubmit[
   ScheduledTask[FileDate[file], Quantity[10, "Seconds"]], 
   HandlerFunctions -> <|
     "ResultReceived" -> (If[#[["EvaluationResult"]] =!= fileDate, 
         fileDate = #[["EvaluationResult"]]; 
         Print["Importing on " ~~ DateString[Now]]; 
         fileContents = Import[file]] &)|>, 
   HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"EvaluationResult"}];
```